# Role based spring security on REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I followed this code base to implement spring security https://github.com/brahalla/Cerberus

I have resource secured after i configured my security like

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based authentication
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Now, i can access `/auth` to generate the token. Then i created a resource like thi s

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
ResponseEntity<?> sayHello() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello", OK);
}
```

and i have hard-coded user defined like this

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1L);
        user.setAuthorities(Roles.ADMIN.name());
        user.setEmail("a@a.com");
        user.setPassword(getEncryptedPass("admin"));
        user.setUsername("hola");
        return CerberusUserFactory.create(user);
    }

    private String getEncryptedPass(String admin) {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder.encode(admin);
    }


}
```

However, whenever i try to access the `api` with `X-Auth-Token` in the header (with generate toke as its value) i am still getting `403` (Access Forbidden). What i am missing here ?

*P.S*: I have already tried `hasRole('Admin')` to `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` ... it didn't work

Comment: Could you please push your code to GitHub? It would be easier to see where is the problem.

Comment: It's already on GitHub. https://github.com/brahalla/Cerberus the only change I made is in `UserDetailServiceImpl` which I have already shared in my question

Comment: This example works fine for me, your problem probably located somewhere else.